# Creating variables from dynamically created Text boxes and labels using C#

Tags: c#, input, dynamic

I am wanting to use to names assigned using .Name to input from text boxes then calculate and output to the labels.

Not sure how I can refer to these inputs as they currently have names but no assigned variables.

Sorry if I don't make much sense I am not a very proficient coder.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<TextBox> Txt1 = new List<TextBox>();
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    var txtbox = new TextBox();
                    txtbox.Location = new Point(163 + (i * 220), (36));
                    txtbox.Name = i + "Names";
                    txtbox.Text = txtbox.Name;
                    txtbox.Width = 40;
                    this.Controls.Add(txtbox);                       
                }
                else if (j>0 && j<6)
                {                      
                    var extratxt = new TextBox();
                    extratxt.Location = new Point(163 + (i * 220), (36+ 36 * j));
                    extratxt.Name = i + "Input" + j;
                    extratxt.Text = extratxt.Name;
                    extratxt.Width = 70;
                    this.Controls.Add(extratxt);

                    var percentbox = new Label();
                    percentbox.Location = new Point(163 + (90+ i * 220), (36 + 36 * j));
                    percentbox.Name = i + "Percent" + j;
                    percentbox.Text = percentbox.Name;
                    percentbox.Width = 50;
                    this.Controls.Add(percentbox);

                    var gradebox = new Label();
                    gradebox.Location = new Point(163 + (150 + i * 220), (36 + 36 * j));
                    gradebox.Name = i + "Grade" + j;
                    gradebox.Text = gradebox.Name;
                    gradebox.Width = 50;
                    this.Controls.Add(gradebox);
                }
                else
                {
                    var totals = new Label();
                    totals.Location = new Point(163 + (i * 220), (36 + 36 * j));
                    totals.Name = i + "Total";
                    totals.Text = totals.Name;
                    totals.Width = 40;
                    this.Controls.Add(totals);
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want each text box and label to have a variable that i can use to refer to them with basically

Comment: If you need to find variables by some string input, use a dictionary.

Comment: so i would so something like dictionary.add 'variable name' then variable name = txtbox.text

Comment: Why not use them directly?

Comment: well since these objects are generated after form load simply using the term 0Names1 or other .Names generated doesn't suffice due to these names noot existing at time of form load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand you correctly.
Basically, your difficulty is how to access the instance stored in list of the dynamically create controls by their name, right?

Well, you can use `.FirstOrDefault()` to select instance with a specific property. For example,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<TextBox> tbList = new List<TextBox>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = "Test" + i.ToString();
        tb.Name = "TextBox" + (i + 1).ToString();
        tb.Location = new Point(0, 25 * i);
        tb.Tag = i;
        tbList.Add(tb);
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
    var tb2 = tbList.FirstOrDefault(tb => tb.Name == "TextBox2");
    if (tb2 != null)
        tb2.Text = "Modified text";

    var sum = tbList.Sum(tb => (int)tb.Tag);
}
```

Comment: i just want each label and textbox to have a variable assigned to them which is the same as their .Name, your code has helped but not completely sure how to implement it in order to calculate information based off the information placed into textbox as inputs. and so i can output calculations as labels

Comment: Sounds the property `Tag` is what you are looking for. See my updated code.